# Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name when use spring4gwt library

Tags: spring, servlets, gwt, mapping

I'm trying to integrate GWT and Spring using the library spring4gwt-0.0.1.jar, but get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name springGwtRemoteServiceServlet
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3275)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3254)
at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1430)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1344)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:876)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:374)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5355)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 6 more
```

My web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>TelephoneBook</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/application-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>    

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.spring4gwt.server.SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>>springGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/TelephoneBook/springGwtServices/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>TelephoneBook.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

What's the matter? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Exactly! How could I have not noticed? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `<servlet-name>>springGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-name>` you have an `>`to much. Is it a copy pase error? (after beginning servlet-name tag

Comment: Exactly! How could I have not noticed? Thank you very much!